How do I get my JavaFX canvas to update, when I have used its GraphicsContext to draw new features?
I am trying to make a falling sand game using JavaFX, and am trying to draw grains of sand to the screen using mouse click events. The physics haven't been implemented yet, so all I'm trying to get working is seeing the pixels on the screen change from the background colour to the colour that I have set the grain of sand as.
I have a timer class that extends AnimationTimer, and the implemented handle function just runs the following render method 30 times per second, in the class of an extended canvas:
public void draw(){
        GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.color(rand.nextFloat(),rand.nextFloat(),rand.nextFloat()));
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        grainMap.forEach(((point, grain) -> {
            System.out.println(grain.getGrainColour());
            gc.setFill(grain.getGrainColour());
            gc.fillRect(point.getX() * SandApplication.GRAIN_SIZE, point.getY() * SandApplication.GRAIN_SIZE,
                    SandApplication.GRAIN_SIZE,
                    SandApplication.GRAIN_SIZE);
        }));
    }

I have also made it so that the canvas handles a mouse click event, that takes the position of the mouse relevant to the canvas and adds a new grain of sand at the point of the mouse on the HashMap called grainmap. I have verified that all of these methods are being called, but yet the window is not rendering any new grains of sand when I click.
How might I be able to fix this?

Create and post a [mre]. There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you have posted.

”the window is not rendering any new grains of sand”. Is the background color changing?
